# Cannot Put Files in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have set up a 2-node hadoop cluster. I have configured the hadoop configuration files. When I start dfs and yarn on my master, it starts namenode(master) and datanode(on slave). But when I run '**jps**' on master it doesn't show the running datanode(slave). However the datanode is actually running because I can see it running calling '**jps**' on slave machine. I have extablished SSH communication between master and slave(Slave is accessible from master) correctly. 
When I run '**jps**' on master it shows

```css
13218 SecondaryNameNode
14327 Jps
12984 NameNode
13388 ResourceManager
```

When I run '**jps**' on slave it shows

```css
10313 DataNode
10828 Jps
10479 NodeManager
```

When I run ***./hadoop/bin/hadoop  fs -ls /*** it shows

```
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - user supergroup          0 2018-04-24 16:15 /new_directory
```

But when I run something to put file on hdfs like ***./hadoop/bin/hadoop fs -put '/home/user/Desktop/words.txt' /newdirectory***, it shows,

```html
18/04/24 16:17:39 WARN hdfs.DataStreamer: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /new_directory/words.txt._COPYING_ could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1733)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirWriteFileOp.chooseTargetForNewBlock(FSDirWriteFileOp.java:265)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:2496)
 at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:828)
  
  ...
```

Here are the configuration files.
**core-site.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
    <configuration>
        <property>
            <name>fs.default.name</name>
            <value>hdfs://master:9000</value>
        </property>
    </configuration>
```

**hdfs-site.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/user/hadoop66_data/data/nameNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>/home/user/hadoop66_data/data/dataNode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
            <value>yarn</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.resource.mb</name>
            <value>512</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
            <value>256</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
            <value>256</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
            <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>master</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>1536</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>1536</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
            <value>128</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled</name>
            <value>false</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

My **/etc/hosts** file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   BL
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
192.168.34.3 master
192.168.32.4 node1
```

**hadoop-2.8.1/etc/hadoop/masters (on master)**

```
master
```

**hadoop-2.8.1/etc/hadoop/slaves (on master)**

```
node1
```

Comment: If you want open the namenode UI, do not you see any datanodes?

Comment: Yes, it shows something like this **Configured Capacity: 0 (0 B)
Present Capacity: 0 (0 B)
DFS Remaining: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used: 0 (0 B)
DFS Used%: NaN%
Under replicated blocks: 0
Blocks with corrupt replicas: 0
Missing blocks: 0**

Comment: There is a tab at the top of the page for datanodes... But anyway, clearly they are not part of the cluster if you have 0 space used or available. On the slave, look at the datanode logs file

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.